# Is it possible to make example.herokuapp.com unable to enter unless by certain dns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web, dns

Currently I make a dns that route from my website (example.com) to herokuapp (e.g. example.herokuapp.com). Soon, I will need to add the meta tags and everything to let google crawl my web. However, if the example.herokuapp.com would be the same as my current domain, which will make it also on google search. Is it possible to let the herokuapp.com to be able to access only via my website? P.S. Currently I am using Ruby On Rails to make my web applications

Comment: It is not clear to me why you what or need to use to domain names pointing to the same application or have two applications serving the same content. Why don't you just use one?

Comment: @spickermann That is what I am trying to do, cuz it works in both website, how can I shut down the herokuapp.com one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) to the top of your `routes.rb` to [redirect](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) all requests with the wrong domain to the preferred domain:

```
constraints(host: /example.herokuapp.com/) do
  get '*path', to: redirect("http://www.example.com/%{path}")
end
```